# Android development device not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting started with Android development. I have an older Samsung Galaxy S2. But Android Studio doesn't recognize the device. I've tried going to the USB utilities but I can't seem to find them. Is my device too old?

Comment: Have you enabled USB Debugging on your phone ?
[Tutorial](https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm) on how to do that

Comment: yes i enabled the debugging on the phone

Answer (score 2):

You will have to enable the "USB debugging" option in your phone:
you will get this after enable the "developer mode" on your phone(aka "developer options" on some devices).

Check [this guide](https://www.greenbot.com/article/2457986/android/how-to-enable-developer-options-on-your-android-phone-or-tablet.html) to enable this mode.

In addition - if you want to test your apps on a real device you will need to have a data USB cable(if you can upload stuff from your phone to your computer than you have the correct type of cable  )

In some devices after enabling developer mode and connecting a cable you should scroll from the top side of the screen (Like in the photo) and click on `USB for file transfer`, and select Transfer files.[image]

Comment: tried this but nothing.  will try buying a new cable. maybe thats my issue.

Comment: before getting a new cable - can you transfer files from your phone to your computer ?

Comment: No, it would only charge the phone.  I couldn't transfer anything.  The new cable works.

Comment: so it all got fixed with the new cable ? can you run your app on your phone?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to enable the Developer mode, if yet doesn't work, take a look at this page https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb, maybe with this driver you will have your problem solved: http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads

You can also check at your adb to make sure your device is connected:

cd  cd c:\Users\Linda\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\

run: adb devices

It must shows your device's ID.

Hope it helps.

Comment: tried this but nothing.  will try buying a new cable. maybe thats my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was not using the correct cable.  I assumed since the phone was charging I was using the correct usb cable to connect to my pc.  Found a different cable, I believe the same cable that came with the phone.  Now my device is found and working.