# USB debugging problem in Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: android-studio, usb-debugging, adb-drivers

I am working with Android studio 3.2.1 windows o/s. My android studio didn't detect  any phone(I tried with huwawei y6 and samsung grand prime).But there was message that USB connected.
But can't get the usb debugging request message in my phone and can't detect my phone. I tried with abd drivers also but no solution.[screenshot after click run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YODVH.png)

Comment: Have you turned on debugging on your Android phone?  Beyond this, I launched an app over 2 years and had perpetual trouble keeping/getting a stable USB connection.  The culprit was an old Android phone and USB cable.  If you want a rock solid USB connection, consider using a new phone and cable.

Comment: Have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972907/8274756) that covers your problem.

Answer (score 0):

do you checked the **USB debugging** checkbox ?
if not :
go to **settings** on the phone then to **About device** then tap on **Build Number** many times after that go back to **settings** you should find **Developer options** appeared tap on it then check **USB debugging** checkbox. 
try this if not working tell me there is another things you can do